# vector calculus directions

Tags: calculus, vectors, electromagnetism

Consider a current density:

$$\vec{j}=j_0(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2})\vec{e_3}$$ if $r\le R$ and $j=0$ if $r\ge R$

where $r$ is the distance from the $x_3$ axis.

I need to use Biot-Savart law to find the direction of the magnetic field:

$$B(r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{J(r') \times {\widehat{n}}}{\eta ^2}$$

So i only need to calculate $$J(r') \times \widehat{n}$$

So this is making me stuck. Since $j$ is only in $e_3$ head, the cross product can be both in $e_1$ and $e_2$ head right? How exactly can i calculate this?

EDIT:

If i use ampere's law:

$$\int B \cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{enc}=\mu_0j_0\int(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\vec{e_3})da$$

I ran into the same problem as before, what do i do witth the directitonal vector $\vec{e_3}$

Comment: Given the problems symmetry, application of Ampere's Law would facilitate the solution.

Comment: For Ampere's law, use a loop of radius $r>R$, and unit normal $\hat z$.  Then, we have $$2\pi r B_\phi =\mu_0 2\pi \int_0^R J_0\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\,r'\,dr'$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $r'<R$, we have $\vec J(\vec r')\times (\vec r-\vec r')=J_0\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\vec B(\vec r)&=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\vec J(\vec r')\times (\vec r-\vec r')}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^3}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\,dz'\\\\
&=\frac{\mu_0J_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')+(z-z'))^{3/2}}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\,dz'\\\\
&=\frac{\mu_0J_0}{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\frac{\mu_0J_0}{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi (r-r'\cos(\phi-\phi'))-\hat rr'\sin(\phi-\phi'))}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat \phi\frac{\mu_0J_0}{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right) (r-r'\cos(\phi'))}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi')}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat \phi\frac{\mu_0J_0}{r}\int_0^{\min(r,R)} \left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right) \,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat \phi\frac{\mu_0J_0}{r}\left(\frac{\min(r^2,R^2)}{2}-\frac{\min(r^4,R^4)}{4R^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi thank you very much for this. But why is in this case $\hat{n} = \vec{r}-\vec{r'}$

Comment: Your $\hat n$ is given by $\hat n =\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|}$.  It is not a unit normal.   Your $\eta^2=|\vec r-\vec r'|^2$.

Comment: hey sorry one more question why is $\vec J(\vec r')\times (\vec r-\vec r')=J_0\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')$ and $e_3$ vanished and $\hat{n} $ became $\phi r - \phi' - r' $?

Comment: also dont quite follow how you computed. the integral, the second step..sry weak calculus

Comment: Note that $\vec J$ has only a $\hat z$ component.  The cross product of $\vec J$ cannot have, therefore, a $\hat z$ component.

Comment: I'm not sure which step you are considering to be the second step.  If you are trying to evaluate an integral, and you're struggling because you claim that you are not versed in elementary calculus, then I suggest having a look at a calculus textbook.  That should help you understand how the integrals are evaluated.

Comment: $$\frac{\mu_0J_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')+(z-z'))^{3/2}}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'\,dz'
=\frac{\mu_0J_0}{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(1-\frac{r'^2}{R^2}\right)\hat (\hat \phi r-\hat \phi'r')}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')}\,r'\,dr'\,d\phi'$$ Here i see you evaluated $z'$ but not tquite sure how you got there

Comment: Apology, but I am still unsure what you're asking.  Do you have a calculus book?

Comment: - i have...as matter of fact i achieved the maximum score in that course but i live in Europe and the vector calculus course is i think a bit different. Thou i also looked at a few books that would be typical text books in the US like multivariate calculus by Mcallum...But i never really saw any integral with univectors in tthem....even the mathematical preparation part presented in most electrodynamics books. - in the question above i meant i dont know exactly what you did with $z-z'$ and the power $^{3/2}$

Comment: $$\int \frac1{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\,dx=\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+C$$Now let $x=z-z'$ and $a^2=r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')$.  Finally, evaluate with limits on $z'$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  The result is $\frac{2}{a^2}=\frac2{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\phi-\phi')}$

Comment: Apology ... that equality sign does not belong

Comment: Sorry to call you up on this, i just wanted to ask how did $$(\hat{\theta}(\hat{r}-r'cos(\theta-\theta')-\hat{r}r'sin(\theta-\theta'))$$ become $$(r-r'cos(\theta'))$$

Comment: @Tomy The expression you wrote appears nowhere in the solution.  Replace your $\theta$ with $\phi$ and replace $\hat \theta$ with $\hat \phi$.  Then, note that the $\hat r$ term integrates to $0$ as the integrand is a $2\pi$-periodic, odd function of $\phi-\phi'$.